# Sold Three Stocks, Why is Market Value Double the Price of Total Netted Value

Tags: united-states, stock-valuation, brokerage

Brokerage is within US bank, I am in USA.

Few days ago I sold some stocks. Total netted value is $300. Settlement will happen in few days.

Right now the Brokerage says Portfolio value is $300, but the market value is $600, exactly double.

Why is market value exactly double. Please tell me before I call Brokerage,

Thank you.

Comment: Is  there any chance that this is a margin account and you are looking at your buying power rather than account value?

Comment: @BobBaerker What is a margin account?

Comment: A [margin account](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marginaccount.asp) is a brokerage account in which the broker lends the customer cash to purchase stocks or other financial products. In the U.S. margin is 50% so if you have $10k of cash in your account, your buying power on 50% would be $20k which like your question, is twice the amount of account value.

Comment: oh no, no margin account!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the stock price doubled suddenly, this makes no sense, and is simply an error in their website / display. Maybe the program is written dumb enough to double count the sold stock.
Either way, it will go away after some time, so no worries.

Unfortunately, this is not uncommon, many of the large brokerage houses have some incorrect data display right after a trade or during settlement period.
For example, the eTrade app shows for several minutes if not hours the outdated cash amount after you bought something, so it looks like you still have the cash plus have the shares. At Vanguard, the money disappears on both ends - so you see too low totals - and comes back after hours. And so on.

Comment: "For example, the eTrade app shows for several minutes if not hours the outdated cash amount after you bought something,"  I think Fidelity does something similar.

Comment: Ok i will check my bank again